# Произношение слова"парикмахерская"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно произносится слово "парикмахерская"? В разговорной речи мне доводилось слышать только [пр**(иэ)х**мАхьрскъjъ], но в словарях подтверждение такой нормы не встречал , а недавно услышал произношение в соответствии с написанием. Так как всё-таки правильно?

Comment: А  "парикмахтерская"  вам  не  встречалось ?

Comment: @bernard, нет, не встречалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> мне доводилось слышать только [пр(иэ)хмАхьрскъjъ]

У вас какая-то смешанная транскрипция, не сказу и поймешь, что имеется в виду.
Первый гласный Вы сознательно пропустили? И "ИЭ" - это что такое?

Если пользоваться "школьным" вариантом (хотя, признаться, я его тоже до конца не знаю), то я произношу [пар'ихмах'эрскайа]. Призвуки гласных не указываю. Про гласные в последнем и предпоследнем слоге - это отдельный разговор, я там слышу слабое а (как в первом заударном), до ъ дело не доходит, подробности опускаю. В отношении гласного после х испытываю некоторое сомнение, но скорее всё-таки э чем и. Вот пожалуй, все, что стоит оговорить. Именно такое произношение слышу повсеместно.

> Словари не рассматривают, ни в одном учебнике не упоминается, как о слове "лёгкий",

У Аванесова, помнится, этот вопрос обсуждался. Искать и цитировать сейчас не могу по причине слабого Интернета. Но по памяти мягкий и легкий - это именно диссимиляция (разуподобление) на встрече двух заднеязычных. Два взрывных заднеязычных подряд - это сложновато для русской фонетики, поэтому вместо первого произносится щелевой.

*Правда, есть еще одно соображение, попробую изложить, хотя это и потребует некоторых текстозатрат.*

*Дело в том, историческое Г в русском было близким к современному украинскому (сравните произношение слов бог, Господи, благовест) и в точности соответствовало озвонченному Х. 
Уточню. Это старорусское Г не совсем украинское (фрикативный веляр, против фрикативного ларингала в уграинском), но на слух воспринимается едва ли не тождественным. В то время как взрвыной русский Г - плозивный веляр - точный звонкий аналог русского К очень от них далек. Поэтому оглушение Г в древне- и старорусском произношении происходило в Х, не в К. Это тоже тянет на объяснение произношения леХкий и мяХкий.*

Но в любом случае ни один из этих факторов никак не мог сказаться на париХмахерской.

(+)

> Вопрос о нормативности остается открытым: надо произносить К или Х?

По современным нормам - К. 
Но произношение париХмахерская слишком распространено чтобы от него просто отмахнуться. 
Я думаю, что оно как минимум допустимо (как разговорное) и, видимо, соответвует старой норме.

Comment: Я  тоже  не  вижу  здесь  даже  вариантов  произношения.  Как  пишется,  так  и  слышится.

Comment: А как насчет чередования К/Х перед сонорным?

Comment: >А как насчет чередования К/Х перед сонорным?  
  
Есть такое чередование? O_o

Я думаю, что тут два фактора, с подобным чередованием никак не связанные.  
Историческое произношение К как Х (сравните "галстух") и ассимиляция под последующее Х.

Answer (score 3):

Можно предположить, что слово не имеет особенностей произношения, так как орфоэпические словари не рассматривают его подробно. В словаре 1987 года оно просто приводится без комментариев, а в новых словарях вообще не упоминается. 
Спорный вопрос о чередовании звука К/Х перед М - оно точно происходит? Тогда  словари должны бы это обозначить.

Странная транскрипция приведена в электронном словаре: парикмахерская - [пар'игм`ах'ирскай'а].

Comment: Словари не рассматривают, ни в одном учебнике не упоминается, как о слове "лёгкий", а повсеместно произносят звук Х. Интересно, почему в словаре нет помет? Хотя спросила коллегу, она произносит К.

Comment: В слове "легкий", наверное, встреча двух заднеязычных Г и К переводит смычной Г во фрикативный Х. А вот почему меняется К перед сонорным согласным?

Comment: Вопрос о нормативности остается открытым: надо произносить К или Х?

Comment: >Словари не рассматривают, ни в одном учебнике не упоминается, как о слове "лёгкий",    

В тексте ответид

Comment: Тем не менее в словаре у Аванесова ничего нет.  В слове "лёгкий" да, два заднеязычных подряд, но в слове "парикмахерская" другая ситуация.

Comment: Чего нет? Про парикмахерскую? Я этого и не обещал.
А про легкий и мягкий, помнится, было в сопровождающей статье.

Comment: Про легкий и мягкий есть во всех учебниках. Кто найдет про парикмахерскую?

Comment: А может быть, произношение первого Х задается вторым Х - такая ассимиляция на расстоянии?

Comment: Произношение [хм] проникло даже в академические словари :  
>**КУАФЁР**, куафёра, муж. (франц.
coiffure) (устар.). **Парихмахер.** Толковый
словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935 1940 …  
http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=26339 
Граждане СССР пользовались таким написанием :  
> П. К. Козлов. Географический дневник Тибетской экспедиции 1923-1926 гг. №5 (1926)  
Подвернулась машина ― и я у фотографа, а затем **у парихмахера**, где встречаюсь с Маршаллом, который и увозит меня сначала в Учком к Жамцарано, а затем к себе, обедать.

Comment: В Малом академическом словаре  (1957 -1984) уже  поправлено на "парикмахер". А как писали в 18-19 веках и не узнаешь - орфография, наверное, везде исправлена.

Comment: Современные советы :  
> Красота, здоровье, отдых: Косметика и парфюм (форум) (2004)  **А в парихмахерской** рекомендовали «народное средство» ― каждый раз перед мытьем (если волосы не капитально грязные, конечно) **наносить майонез** минут на 10, потом тщательно смывать.

Comment: Неплохо смотрится - такое "симметричное" слово.

Comment: Вот еще симметричное слово, оно прекрасно иллюстрирует некоторые местные порядки)))  
> М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Губернские очерки (1856-1857)  
Потому что тут, знаете, **шахер-махер**, рука руку моет…